# Wrong result from Rectangle.contains() in java

Tags: java, awt, rectangles, java-2d

It appears that the `contains()` method in `Rectangle` is not inclusive to the bottom right corner.

For example the following code returns "false";

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
System.out.println(r.contains(100, 100));
```

Comment: The `Rectangle` API does not specifically state inclusion or exclusion, unfortunately`......    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains-int-int-

Comment: Seems like the correct behaviour to me.  These co-ordinates are actual pixels on the screen, not mathematical points.  A rectangle that includes both `(0,0)` and `(100,100)` would have to have a width and height of at least `101` pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quoted from the Rectangle API (Java 8):

> public Rectangle(int x,
>                    int y,
>                    int width,
>                    int height)
>  Constructs a new Rectangle whose upper-left corner is specified as (x,y) and whose width and height are
>   specified by the arguments of the same name.

Using Width and Height with the starting `Point` of (0,0) means the `Rectangle` has points from (0,0) to (99,99) - 100 pixels of width and 100 pixels of height, based on the given starting pixel of (0,0) which is always included in the `Rectangle`.

This means that (100,100) will indeed not be included in the constructed `Rectangle`. Based on the logic above, (100,100) will be contained in the following (verified using an [online java compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)):

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1,1,100,100);
```

References:

- [The Rectangle API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the API wrongly states that the "upper left corner" is (x,y) when according to the accepted answer and my own experience, (x,y) is the lower left corner.